Card design with long and short text options
I am designing a card for uploaded files. The card displays the file name, the company or user who uploaded the file, and the upload date. The data should be easy to scan, so the same data on different cards is aligned at the same height.

With these constrains I have the problem that the card looks awful with short texts.
Do you have any suggestions to avoid this?

Is this similar to the question here? But that question donot have a final answer too. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/120958/on-a-card-ui-with-less-than-usual-text-should-i-leave-the-card-size-as-is-or-m

How can you guarantee that users will write a short file name? Otherwise you fall back on the same problem later on.

Can you explain what you mean by "looks awful"?  To me, the short-text one looks much better than the others.

Don't be afraid of blank spaces
"With these constraints":

Same position
Exact text

The only possible procedure is to deal with blank spaces.
In the current card there are two very notorious blanks. One solution is trying to suppress at least one of them.
For example, by setting a bottom vertical alignment in the field intended for the company name:

The final look is the card with a title and a footer.


Thx for that Idea. I think that would be a good solution


The data should be easy to scan, so the same data on different cards is aligned at the same height.

Another option could be to use small different logos in front of each component (the filename, the company, the date).
Logos can help users to see at a glance the different types of information and quickly "align" them when reading the different cards.
In that sense, you could avoid to physically align the components and regroup the lines together, thus avoiding the blank lines.
